# How to setup auto-completion with git on openBSD?

Tags: linux, git, terminal, openbsd

I want to setup auto-completion for git commands in ksh and openBSD 5.8/5.9.
 Somehow it was installed previously and suddenly disappeared so I have to type or copy and paste large amounts of text.

It should work as in OSX or Ubuntu, where you type `git merge X...` and press the "tab" key so it completes the rest of the branch name in terminal.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to have a script for that. Unix/git-bash are already have this
script.

Read about it here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Basics-Tips-and-Tricks
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Basics-Tips-and-Tricks#Auto-Completion

You have many options on how to install it. Simply choose the right way for you.,

https://github.com/bobthecow/git-flow-completion/wiki/Install-Bash-git-completion

---

#### OpenBSD Script

Here is a link to the OpenBSD script which you can use.
The file has header with all the instructions how to do it.

http://www.ualberta.ca/dept/aict/uts/software/openbsd/ports/4.6/i386/obj/git-1.7.0/git-1.7.0/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash

---

#### The above script instructions:

```bash
#!bash
#
# bash completion support for core Git.
#
# Copyright (C) 2006,2007 Shawn O. Pearce <spearce@spearce.org>
# Conceptually based on gitcompletion (http://gitweb.hawaga.org.uk/).
# Distributed under the GNU General Public License, version 2.0.
#
# The contained completion routines provide support for completing:
#
#    *) local and remote branch names
#    *) local and remote tag names
#    *) .git/remotes file names
#    *) git 'subcommands'
#    *) tree paths within 'ref:path/to/file' expressions
#    *) common --long-options
#
# To use these routines:
#
#    1) Copy this file to somewhere (e.g. ~/.git-completion.sh).
#    2) Added the following line to your .bashrc:
#        source ~/.git-completion.sh
#
#    3) Consider changing your PS1 to also show the current branch:
#        PS1='[\u@\h \W$(__git_ps1 " (%s)")]\$ '
#
#       The argument to __git_ps1 will be displayed only if you
#       are currently in a git repository.  The %s token will be
#       the name of the current branch.
#
#       In addition, if you set GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE to a nonempty
#       value, unstaged (*) and staged (+) changes will be shown next
#       to the branch name.  You can configure this per-repository
#       with the bash.showDirtyState variable, which defaults to true
#       once GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE is enabled.
#
#       You can also see if currently something is stashed, by setting
#       GIT_PS1_SHOWSTASHSTATE to a nonempty value. If something is stashed,
#       then a '$' will be shown next to the branch name.
#
#       If you would like to see if there're untracked files, then you can
#       set GIT_PS1_SHOWUNTRACKEDFILES to a nonempty value. If there're
#       untracked files, then a '%' will be shown next to the branch name.
```

Comment: This one is for bash. I guess there's nothing for ksh ?

Comment: Dont know, im a bash/sh/zsh user. never used ksh

Comment: It doesn't work for ksh, but your script works for bash. I will wait to find a ksh alternative and If there isn't any, I will move to bash.

Comment: Glad to help. if it helped you please be kind to accept and vote for the answer.appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Download the bash completion file here:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash

I put it in:
/usr/local/share/bash-completion/completions/git

Then make sure your shell is set to bash and then source that file.  My bashrc section looks like this:
https://gist.github.com/ckuttruff/db8349e0cc3a1930dc4f5f17a042e1f6

Answer (score 0):

Afaik there is no git auto-completion script for ksh. What you can do is add hard coded completion entries to the git command. Unfortunately this prevents file auto-completion.

```sh
# Add auto-completion entries to git
set -A complete_git status commit clone rebase bisect --patch --interactive
```